# How to Export certificate key to PEM format?

Tags: keytool

My keystore is deleted, and I try to chat with Google playstore developer and I ask that my keystore app be reset, then they sent instructions like this:

> Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a
>   new key:
>
> ```
> keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
> ```
>
> This key must be a 2048 bit RSA key and have 25-year validity.
>
> Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:
>
> ```
> keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
> ```
>
> Reply to this email and attach the upload_certificate.pem file.

My question is how to Export the certificate for that key to PEM format?

I try to using keytool.exe in folder C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin the command prompt keytool.exe can not been write (force close)

Answer (score 2):

keytool is provided in JDK, not JRE. You can install a JDK 1.8 for example and use keytool command from the path **C:\Program Files\Java\JDK_1.8\bin\keytool.exe** in Windows CMD terminal in Administrator mode(preferably).

The commands you provided are meant to generate a keypair and to export the certificate. So, if you have a proper keytool installed, you can execute your commands successfully and export the certificate.

For exporting certificate, if path not given it will export the ceritificate in bin folder.